# JSP Page conflict error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jsp-tags

I use resin-3.1.7a as my application server,and most of my jsp files is starts with<%@ page contentType="text/vnd.wap.wml;charset=UTF-8"%>&65292;It works well in resin-3.0.14&65292;but when I moved the application to resin-3.1.7,It doesn;t work,the error is:

contentType 'text/html' conflicts with previous value of contentType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'.  Check the .jsp and any included .jsp files for conflicts.

```
                   10:  <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
                   11:  
                   12:  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
                   13:  <!DOCTYPE html>
                   14:   <script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

instead

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```